# passwords is changing for all users in django rest

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have made an API for password change but it's changing the passwords for all users instead of only one user.

seriealizer code is below:

```
class ChangePasswordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
password1 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True, validators=[validate_password])
password2 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)
old_password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('old_password', 'password1', 'password2')

def validate(self, attrs):
    if attrs['password1'] != attrs['password2']:
        raise serializers.ValidationError({"password": "Password fields didn't match."})

    return attrs

def validate_old_password(self, value):
    user = self.context['request'].user
    if not user.check_password(value):
        raise serializers.ValidationError({"old_password": "Old password is not correct"})
    return value

def update(self, instance, validated_data):

    instance.set_password(validated_data['password1'])
    instance.save()
    return  instance
```

view code is below:

```
class ChangePasswordView(generics.UpdateAPIView):

queryset = User.objects.all()
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
serializer_class = ChangePasswordSerializer
```

what is wrong with this code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Password change is very straight forward. Django already has a form to do it. Try the below code:

```py
    @api_view(['PUT'])
    @permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
    def change_password(request):
        form = PasswordChangeForm(request.user, request.data)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            serializer = UserSerializer(request.user)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(form.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Read this page for more information on how to build user auth methods using DRF: https://kushgoyal.com/creating-a-sceure-login-api-using-drf-token-auth/

url for this will be of this format:
`url(r'change_password/', views.change_password)`

Comment: thanks for responding to me, could you also tell me url for this view please.  `url(r'change_password/<int:pk>/', change_password)` it is giving Page Not Found error.

Comment: Thanks alot, there is one more thing. It is only changing password for ID=1. how do I change password for users which have Id=2,3 or so on

Comment: it will change the password of the currently logged in user ie `request.user`

Comment: Okay, I appreciate your time and patience. thanks alot